# two different outputs on two different ipe with the same code, is it a problem with my code?

Tags: python, arrays, list, output, median

so I'm trying to solve a Leetcode problem.

the input is two sorted lists and the output should be their median

```
class Solution(object):
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :rtype: float
        """
        newlist = nums1 + nums2
        newlist = sorted(newlist)
        if len(newlist) < 2:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            if len(newlist) % 2 == 0:
                return ((newlist[int((len(newlist)//2))-1]) + (newlist[int((len(newlist))//2)]))/2
            else:
                return newlist[(int((len(newlist)+1)//2))-1]
        # nums1 = [1,2]
        # nums2 [3,4]
        # newlist = [1,2,3,4]
        # len(newlist) % 2 = 0
        # return should give (2+3)/2 == 2.5000
        # return actually give 2.0000
```

this is the code, I tried doing the path of the lists in the comments to see if I'm doing something wrong.

the output should be 2.5000 (which I'm getting it on Jupyter notebook when running the same code), but when running it on Leetcode I'm getting 2.0000 as the output.

Is it something wrong with my code? and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Are the python versions different? The division operator behaves differently in Python 2 and 3

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you so much, i'm new to python and only learned python 3 so I didn't know this thing could happen. I divided by 2.0 beside 2 after checking on google